# How to fill values from multiple dataframe into new empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe with different value.

#1 Dataframe

| Player A | Time | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5.83 | 10.21 | 3.12 | 2.33 |
| 1 | 2 | 5.64 | 10.16 | 3.15 | 2.37 |
| 1 | 3 | 5.60 | 10.11 | 3.19 | 2.42 |
| 1 | 4 | 5.55 | 10.08 | 3.22 | 2.46 |
| 1 | 5 | 5.52 | 10.02 | 3.27 | 2.50 |
| 1 | 6 | 5.48 | 9.97 | 3.33 | 2.55 |

#2 Dataframe

| Player B | Time | e | f | g | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7.77 | 9.63 | 5.61 | 4.33 |
| 1 | 2 | 7.79 | 9.66 | 5.66 | 4.37 |
| 1 | 5 | 7.83 | 9.72 | 5.72 | 4.42 |
| 1 | 6 | 7.96 | 9.77 | 5.77 | 4.56 |
| 1 | 7 | 9.22 | 9.83 | 6.23 | 4.67 |
| 1 | 9 | 9.41 | 9.97 | 6.54 | 5.55 |

I am trying to create a new dataframe and filling the new dataframe with the values from the two dataframe above.

This is my expected output:

| Index | Player A | Player B | Time | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5.83 | 10.21 | 3.12 | 2.33 | 7.77 | 9.63 | 5.61 | 4.33 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 5.64 | 10.16 | 3.15 | 2.37 | 7.79 | 9.66 | 5.66 | 4.37 |
| 2 | 1 | nan | 3 | 5.60 | 10.11 | 3.19 | 2.42 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | 1 | nan | 4 | 5.55 | 10.08 | 3.22 | 2.46 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 5.52 | 10.02 | 3.27 | 2.50 | 7.83 | 9.72 | 5.72 | 4.42 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 5.48 | 9.97 | 3.33 | 2.55 | 7.96 | 9.77 | 5.77 | 4.56 |
| 6 | nan | 1 | 7 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 7.96 | 9.77 | 5.77 | 4.56 |
| 7 | nan | nan | 8 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 8 | nan | 1 | 9 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 9.41 | 9.97 | 6.54 | 5.55 |

I had create a dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Player A', 'Player B', 'Time','C','D','E','F','G','H'], index=range(10))`

My current output is :

| Index | Player A | Player B | Time | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 4 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 5 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 6 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 7 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 8 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |

I"m stuck after this step. How do I solve this problem for the further step?

Note: I'm using python 3.9

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be as follows:

- First, use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to combine the two DataFrames. Parameter `on` should be set to column `Time` and `how` to `outer`.
- Next, we use [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to make column `Time` the index, and pass `range(1,10)` to [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to add any missing `Time` values (i.e. `8` in this case).
- Finally, we reset the index again ([`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)), and use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to get the columns in the desired order.

```
res = (df
       .merge(df2, on='Time', how='outer')
       .set_index('Time').reindex(range(1,10))
       .reset_index(drop=False)
       .loc[:,['Player A','Player B', 'Time'] + [*'abcdefgh']])

res

   Player A  Player B  Time     a      b     c     d     e     f     g     h
0       1.0       1.0     1  5.83  10.21  3.12  2.33  7.77  9.63  5.61  4.33
1       1.0       1.0     2  5.64  10.16  3.15  2.37  7.79  9.66  5.66  4.37
2       1.0       NaN     3  5.60  10.11  3.19  2.42   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3       1.0       NaN     4  5.55  10.08  3.22  2.46   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4       1.0       1.0     5  5.52  10.02  3.27  2.50  7.83  9.72  5.72  4.42
5       1.0       1.0     6  5.48   9.97  3.33  2.55  7.96  9.77  5.77  4.56
6       NaN       1.0     7   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  9.22  9.83  6.23  4.67
7       NaN       NaN     8   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
8       NaN       1.0     9   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  9.41  9.97  6.54  5.55
```

**Data used**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Player A': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}, 
        'Time': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6}, 
        'a': {0: 5.83, 1: 5.64, 2: 5.6, 3: 5.55, 4: 5.52, 5: 5.48}, 
        'b': {0: 10.21, 1: 10.16, 2: 10.11, 3: 10.08, 4: 10.02, 5: 9.97}, 
        'c': {0: 3.12, 1: 3.15, 2: 3.19, 3: 3.22, 4: 3.27, 5: 3.33}, 
        'd': {0: 2.33, 1: 2.37, 2: 2.42, 3: 2.46, 4: 2.5, 5: 2.55}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'Player B': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}, 
         'Time': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 7, 5: 9}, 
         'e': {0: 7.77, 1: 7.79, 2: 7.83, 3: 7.96, 4: 9.22, 5: 9.41}, 
         'f': {0: 9.63, 1: 9.66, 2: 9.72, 3: 9.77, 4: 9.83, 5: 9.97}, 
         'g': {0: 5.61, 1: 5.66, 2: 5.72, 3: 5.77, 4: 6.23, 5: 6.54}, 
         'h': {0: 4.33, 1: 4.37, 2: 4.42, 3: 4.56, 4: 4.67, 5: 5.55}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

---

*Note*. Incidentally, I trust that your expected output has erroneous values for the row at `Index 6`. I mean the values here in the second row:

```
output.loc[5:6, [*'efgh']]

      e     f     g     h
5  7.96  9.77  5.77  4.56
6  7.96  9.77  5.77  4.56
```

This should be:

```
res.loc[5:6, [*'efgh']]

      e     f     g     h
5  7.96  9.77  5.77  4.56
6  9.22  9.83  6.23  4.67
```